# How to draw a shaded boundary using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

How can I draw a simple shaded region such as the one shown below using TikZ?

[image: shaded boundary]

The shaded region bounded by the equation

```
r1r2r3 - r1 - r2 - r3 + 2cos(theta)
```

and is `r1=r2=r3=4`. The boundary will change slightly for different values of `theta`. For the purpose of this, we can assume `theta=0`.

The idea here is to use TikZ with certain functions and `fillbetween` commands but this becomes tricky for 3D plots. This example could then be used to draw more involved boundaries

Any tips/relevant posts would be helpful!

**EDIT**

I would ideally like a solution that just uses TiKZ and not pstricks.

Comment: What is your figure? A lot of details should be added, in my opinion

Comment: @BlackMild, thank you for the suggestion. Please see updated question.

Comment: What about using some faster programming language to generate list of coordinates then feed that one to TikZ instead? (that would probably also be *faster*.

Comment: @user202729, that would be the go-to method if this fails. Ideally, I would like to learn how to approach this via TikZ alone

Comment: Well if I recalled correctly TikZ does not have a "real" 3D engine, so first step would be to let the viewpoint be (x, y, z) (given the image I assume you want perspective projection instead of central projection, as the bottom face is much larger than the top face in the projection), hope that the formula is simple/can be expressed in elementary functions, etc.

Comment: Doesn't sound fun. Plugging in something with a 3D engine sounds like less work.

Comment: Anyway do you require central/perspective projection, or is parallel (orthographic) projection okay?

Comment: A 2D projection may obscure some of the details, particularly when looking for a solution that can be extended to more involved boundaries, so a central/perspective would be more suited.

Comment: Related question, there is [pgfplots - plot 3d graphs of functions defined implicitly - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140278/plot-3d-graphs-of-functions-defined-implicitly) for plotting implicit 3d surface, but I'm not sure if the engine support transparency. There's also [tikz pgf - Drawing intersecting 3D surface plots - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176534/drawing-intersecting-3d-surface-plots) for transparent, but it's for pstricks

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I think that implicit surfaces can be sketched in Ti*k*Z when the level curves (or other hyperplane sections) can be drawn.  For the surface *xyz   - x - y - z + 2 = 0* (in fact for any value of *theta* in the question), the level curves are hyperbolas and it is not difficult to draw them.

**Some comments**

1. I changed the coordinates as to have the singular point at the origin, i.e. I considered the surface defined by *xyz + xy + yz + zx = 0*.  It is only a translation of the previous one.
2. Looking at the example that it was given, I represented only a "sheet" of the surface; explicitly I considered the portion of the surface living in the cube *[-1, 5]^3* and which is swept out by only one branch of each *z=h* hyperbola.
3. For *z=0* the hyperbola degenerates into the union of two lines.  For *z=-1* it degenerates again into two lines, but one is at infinity.  For these reasons, the drawing of the level curve depends on the sign of *z*.  In the neighborhood of *-1* things are more subtle since the limits of Ti*k*Z are easily reached.  For example, if the first `\foreach` is performed for `\i=1` or `\i=2`, the curves obtained are not "real" (or at least the intended ones).
4. The code might seem long, but what counts are the first two `\foreach` commands that draw the *z=h* level curves.  Afterwards, they are just copied and modified in order to obtain the *x=h* and *y=h* level curves.
5. Each branch of a hyperbola is drawn as a parametrized curve; the bounds of the parameter are computed to obtain only the portion inside  the cube.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\xdefinecolor{Cy}{RGB}{17, 170, 187}
\xdefinecolor{VB}{RGB}{102, 25, 240}

\tikzmath{
  integer \N-, \N+;
  \N- = 12;
  \N+ = 50;
  real \a;
  \a = 5;
}
\tikzset{
  pics/level curve+/.style args={height=#1, varbound=#2, color=#3}{%
    code={%
      \draw[#3, variable=\t, domain=-#2:#2, samples=40]
      plot ({#1/(#1 +1)*(exp(\t) -1)}, {#1/(#1 +1)*(exp(-\t) -1)});
    }
  },
  pics/level curve-/.style args={height=#1, varbound=#2, color=#3}{%
    code={%
      \draw[#3, variable=\t, domain=-#2:#2, samples=40]
      plot ({-#1/(#1 +1)*(exp(\t) +1)}, {-#1/(#1 +1)*(exp(-\t) +1)});
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{76}{67}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
    % axes first part
    \draw (-1, 0, 0) -- (\a +.2, 0, 0);
    \draw (0, -1, 0) -- (0, \a +.2, 0);
    \draw (0, 0, -1) -- (0, 0, \a +.2);
    
    %%% $z=h$ level curves
    % close to $0^-$
    \foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \h using {-(\N- +1 -\i)/(\N- +1))*\a/(\a +1)},
    evaluate=\i as \b using {ln(-(\h +1)*\a/\h -1)}]
    in {1, 2, 3, 4, ..., \N-}{
      \path[canvas is xy plane at z=\h, transform shape] (0, 0)
      pic {level curve-={height=\h, varbound=\b, color=Cy}};
    }    

    % $h=0$
    \draw[Cy, canvas is xy plane at z=0] (0, \a) |- (\a, 0);

    % $h>0$
    \foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \h using {(\i/\N+)*\a},
    evaluate=\i as \b using {ln((\h +1)*\a/\h +1)}]
    in {1, 2, ..., \N+}{
      \path[canvas is xy plane at z=\h, transform shape] (0, 0)
      pic {level curve+={height=\h, varbound=\b, color=Cy}};
    }

    %%% $y=h$ level curves
    % close to $0^-$
    \foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \h using {-(\N- +1 -\i)/(\N- +1))*\a/(\a +1)},
    evaluate=\i as \b using {ln(-(\h +1)*\a/\h -1)}]
    in {3, 4, ..., \N-}{
      \path[canvas is xz plane at y=\h, transform shape] (0, 0)
      pic {level curve-={height=\h, varbound=\b, color=Cy}};
    }    

    % $h=0$
    \draw[Cy, thin, canvas is xz plane at y=0] (0, \a) |- (\a, 0);
    
    % $h>0$
    \foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \h using {(\i/\N+)*\a},
    evaluate=\i as \b using {ln((\h +1)*\a/\h +1)}]
    in {1, 2, ..., \N+}{
      \path[canvas is xz plane at y=\h, transform shape] (0, 0)
      pic {level curve+={height=\h, varbound=\b, color=Cy}};
    }

    %%% $x=h$ level curves
    % close to $0^-$
    \foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \h using {-(\N- +1 -\i)/(\N- +1))*\a/(\a +1)},
    evaluate=\i as \b using {ln(-(\h +1)*\a/\h -1)}]
    in {3, 4, ..., \N-}{
      \path[canvas is yz plane at x=\h, transform shape] (0, 0)
      pic {level curve-={height=\h, varbound=\b, color=Cy}};
    }    

    % $h=0$
    \draw[VB, canvas is yz plane at x=0] (0, \a) |- (\a, 0);
    
    % $h>0$
    \foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \h using {(\i/\N+)*\a},
    evaluate=\i as \b using {ln((\h +1)*\a/\h +1)}]
    in {1, 2, ..., \N+}{
      \path[canvas is yz plane at x=\h, transform shape] (0, 0)
      pic {level curve+={height=\h, varbound=\b, color=VB}};
    }

    %%% axes second part
    \begin{scope}[arrows={->[length=1ex, width=1.5ex]}]
      \draw (\a, 0, 0) -- (\a +2, 0, 0)  node[pos=1.2] {$x$};
      \draw (0, \a, 0) -- (0, \a +2, 0)  node[pos=1.2] {$y$};
      \draw (0, 0, \a) -- (0, 0, \a +2)  node[pos=1.2] {$z$};          
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```